# Get 2 bars from mouse click and project 3rd point in time

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to grab user input from mouse click identifying 2 points (High bar and low bar) and calculate the difference between them in terms of number of bars? And then project a third point which would occur after X bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's being considered as an addition to input functionality, but we're not there yet.